# Foreach / If with CSV file - update object value in object with properties

Tags: powershell

I have a TAB separated TXT file which I'm adding a Header line in. Then I need to read the file line by line and if I find a specific value in one of the cells of a certain header column, I want to change a value of a different cell in the same row but different header column. It all works apart from the negative value.

My TXT file looks like this:

```
20230920    Invoice     59104065563 0001443.00  0000123.00  20230918    1631001                 4500026591  100151      
20230920    Invoice     60105000664 0000220.00  0000020.00  20230910    116608                  4500025378  100155      
20230920    Invoice     91624746327 0000550.00  0000050.00  20230827    5246                    4500374941  100157      
20230920    Credit      71127603418 0000018.00  0000000.00  20221010    081249A                             100154
```

Here is my code:

```
$TXTfile = Import-Csv "C:\temp\UPLOADFOR.txt" -Header "Date","Invoice_Ind","ABN","Gross_Invoice_Amount","GST","Invoice_Date","Invoice No.","Purchase_Order_No.","Supplier_No." -Delimiter "`t" 
$TXTfile

foreach ($row in $TXTfile) 
{
    if ($row.Invoice_Ind -eq 'Credit')  
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = (([decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount) *-1)
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
    else 
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = [decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
}
```

So, basically I want to archive to change the Gross_Invoice_Amount from 0000018.00 in line 4 to -18.00 (minus -18.00 excluding the leading zeros) when the value "Credit" was found in the Invoice_Ind column for the row. Otherwise, I just change the value of the Gross_Invoice_Amount to exclude leading zeros.

Expected result to be added to a TXT output file:

```
Date    Invoice_Ind ABN Gross_Invoice_Amount    GST Invoice_Date    Invoice No. Purchase_Order_No.  Supplier_No.
20230920    Invoice     59104065563 1443.00 123.00  20230918    1631001 4500026591  100151
20230920    Invoice     60105000664 220.00  20.00   20230910    116608  4500025378  100155
20230920    Invoice     91624746327 550.00  50.00   20230827    5246    4500374941  100157
20230920    Credit      71127603418 -18.00  0.00    20221010    081249A                             100154
```

Comment: What output are you getting currently and what is wrong about it?

Comment: I have not created an output file yet. The problem is that the value in Gross_Invoice_Amount does not get converted into a negative value when finding the word "Credit" in Invoice_Ind for that row.

Comment: What console output do you get from your ```write-host``` lines? Try delimiting the values in case there are hidden spaces like ```Credit   ``` or something - e.g. ```write-host “Invoice indicator is: ‘$($row.Invoice_Ind)’, ‘$($row.Gross_Invoice_Amount)’”``` and see what that displays…

Comment: This is the console output I get at th moment:

Invoice indicator is:  Invoice  1443.00
Invoice indicator is:  Invoice  220.00
Invoice indicator is:  Invoice  550.00
Invoice indicator is:  Credit  18.00
I think sonehting is wrong with "$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = (([decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount) *-1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if ($row.Invoice_Ind -match 'Credit')` insead of **-eq** as there could be hidden spaces in your value.

```
$TXTfile = Import-Csv "C:\temp\UPLOADFOR.txt" -Header "Date","Invoice_Ind","ABN","Gross_Invoice_Amount","GST","Invoice_Date","Invoice No.","Purchase_Order_No.","Supplier_No." -Delimiter "`t" 
$TXTfile | ft

foreach ($row in $TXTfile) 
{
    if ($row.Invoice_Ind -match 'Credit')  
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = (([decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount) *-1)
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
    else 
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = [decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
}

$TXTfile | ft
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm the behavior you are seeing. This is what I get when executing your code.

```
$TXTfile = Import-Csv "C:\temp\UPLOADFOR.txt" -Header "Date","Invoice_Ind","ABN","Gross_Invoice_Amount","GST","Invoice_Date","Invoice No.","Purchase_Order_No.","Supplier_No." -Delimiter "`t"

$TXTfile | ft

Date     Invoice_Ind ABN         Gross_Invoice_Amount GST        Invoice_Date Invoice No. Purchase_Order_No. Supplier_No.
----     ----------- ---         -------------------- ---        ------------ ----------- ------------------ ------------
20230920 Invoice     59104065563 0001443.00           0000123.00 20230918     1631001     4500026591         100151
20230920 Invoice     60105000664 0000220.00           0000020.00 20230910     116608      4500025378         100155
20230920 Invoice     91624746327 0000550.00           0000050.00 20230827     5246        4500374941         100157
20230920 Credit      71127603418 0000018.00           0000000.00 20221010     081249A     100154

foreach ($row in $TXTfile)
{
    if ($row.Invoice_Ind -eq 'Credit')
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = (([decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount) *-1)
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
    else
    {
        $row.Gross_Invoice_Amount = [decimal]$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
        Write-host 'Invoice indicator is: ' $row.Invoice_Ind,$row.Gross_Invoice_Amount
    }
}

Invoice indicator is:  Invoice 1443
Invoice indicator is:  Invoice 220
Invoice indicator is:  Invoice 550
Invoice indicator is:  Credit -18

$TXTfile | ft

Date     Invoice_Ind ABN         Gross_Invoice_Amount GST        Invoice_Date Invoice No. Purchase_Order_No. Supplier_No.
----     ----------- ---         -------------------- ---        ------------ ----------- ------------------ ------------
20230920 Invoice     59104065563              1443,00 0000123.00 20230918     1631001     4500026591         100151
20230920 Invoice     60105000664               220,00 0000020.00 20230910     116608      4500025378         100155
20230920 Invoice     91624746327               550,00 0000050.00 20230827     5246        4500374941         100157
20230920 Credit      71127603418               -18,00 0000000.00 20221010     081249A     100154
```

Comment: I don't get the negative value. All my output is positive values. Not getting -18.00